# WebSQL - Alternative for Cordova-App

Tags: sql, cordova, angular

Cordova-Docu says:

> WebSQL Not supported by all Cordova platforms. More complex to work
>   with than LocalStorage or IndexedDB. The API is deprecated. It is
>   unlikely to ever be supported on platforms that don't currently
>   support it, and it may be removed from platforms that do. Imposes a
>   rigid structure that must be defined up-front. Limited total amount of
>   storage (typically around 5MB).

- [source](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html#websql)

Id like to deploy an Angular2-Cordova-App with a SQL-like App on client-side. Can anyone recomend an alternative? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use SQLite with a plugin like [this](https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2).

Just quoting from the readme:

> This plugin provides a WebSQL-compatible API to store data in a
>   Cordova/PhoneGap/Ionic app, by using a SQLite database on the native
>   side. The main benefits are:
>
> 1. unlimited and durable storage
> 2. prepopulated databases
> 3. support where WebSQL isn't available (namely iOS WKWebView)

---

Depending on your needs you could also use something like [LocalForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage).

Comment: Ah, how did I not see that! I will also try Purus suggestions, but this seems to be it. Thank you evry much! :)

Answer (score 1):

The below repo might help you. You can use it to use websql but actually without using sql.

https://github.com/paulocaldeira17/angular-websql

**Example for inserting:**

```
$scope.db.insert('user', {"username": 'pc', "password": '1234', 'age': 22}).then(function(results) {
  console.log(results.insertId);
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I will try this, and also checkout Phonologs suggestion (SQLite). :)